Get the no.of records Inserted in last 10 days
In my table I didn't have primary key and forgot to add timestamp column. Now I would need to find the records with date time of insertion in last 10 days. Is there a way to find this? If yes then how?
I have googled and find below query:
SELECT 
    [Current LSN],
    [Operation],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Begin Time],
    [End Time],
    [Transaction Name],
    [Transaction SID],    
    [Page ID],
    [Slot ID],
    [Lock Information],
    [XAct ID],    
    [AllocUnitName],
    [Num Elements] 
FROM 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE 
    Operation = 'LOP_INSERT_ROWS'
    AND AllocUnitName LIKE '%EHSRegis%';

But the output of this query is not readable also when I am currently inserting manually any record it showing me for some time, then after some time this query returns nothing. [Begin Time] & [End Time] is NULL

If you don't record when your data is inserted, then you can't get this information; SQL Server doesn't store such meta data about rows (it's up to you to define the meta data you need). A timestamp (rowversion) column wouldn't have helped you anyway; it's a binary(8) value and has nothing to do with times. You would have needed to use a datetime2 column.

Restore a backup and compare with the current data. Otherwise not possible, you are wasting your time.

Can't we recover from sql log files where the transaction history being stored?

If the DB is in full recovery mode and you have transaction log backups then yes you can restore to any point in time & look at the data.

You'll still need to restore backwards, @SumeetKumar . If you need a specific point in time 10 days ago (say at 15:00 on 2024-07-16) then you'll need to RESTORE your backup from prior to then, and then use your transaction log backups to restore to the correct point in time.

Does this answer your question? How to restore SQL Server database to a particular time?

Does this answer your question? Restore database to point in time from full backup only

I already have data. Just I want date & time of their insert transaction

So, do you have access to transaction logs or full backup from 10 days ago? Otherwise this is a pointless exercise. What does: select recovery_model_desc from sys.databases where database_id = DB_ID() returns?

@siggemannen It returns FULL

That's good, then you should have backups somewhere probably

Could it be feasible to read .LDF (as this file would store all transaction log) file using T-Sql statements to get those INSERT transaction happened for last 10 days to get date & time?

Yes, if the files are still around, see fn_dump_dblog, but it's not easy. What do you need this info for? Maybe just tell them it's not possible

It's unlikely your log file has data for transactions for the last 10 days, @SumeetKumar , as your log is likely being backed up every 15 minutes at least.

Add a date time created column and then in 10 short days you will have a solution
